# How to clone gitlab repository via bower.json in a jenkins job when grunt build is executing?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gruntjs, jenkins-pipeline, bower

I was trying out set up a Jenkins job for my UI project which builds with grunt. when I tried to build the UI project in the Jenkins job it keep stuck at the "Checkout & Build" stage grunt build process(I don't get any error logs & attached a screenshot below). And also I checked some questions and answers here in stack overflow but so far couldn't find any proper solution. The Jenkins Pipeline and parameters I used as bellow. (And also note this: Git lab and the Jenkins run on the same AWS server two different docker instances.)

#### project folder and file structure

```
grunt-task 
src  
vendor  
.bowerrc  
Gruntfile.js  
README.md  
bower.json  
module.prefix   
module.suffix  
package.json
```

#### Pipeline Parameters and their default values

1.Build_Environment (Development, Production)
2.projectId (eg:- 5624)
3.manualBuildUserName (gitusername)
4.manualBuildUserEmail (gitemail)
5.DevelopmentDeployPath(path to deploy folder)
6.development_branch (dev)
7.production_branch(master) etc.

#### Pipeline

```
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

    node {     
        def committers = "" 
        try{

            stage("Initiate") {  
                sourceUrlList = []
                redentialsId = 'my_pcr_gitlab_credentials'
                blockPipeline = false

                tarIt = true
                if(env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl && env.gitlabSourceBranch ){
                    sourceBranch = env.gitlabSourceBranch
                    print sourceBranch
                    if(sourceBranch == env.development_branch){
                        buildEnv = 'Development'
                    }else {
                        blockPipeline = true
                    }
                    gitlabUserName = env.gitlabUserName
                    gitlabUserEmail = env.gitlabUserEmail
                } else {
                    buildEnv = env.Build_Environment
                    sourceBranch = env[buildEnv.toLowerCase() + '_branch']
                    gitlabUserName = env.manualBuildUserName
                    gitlabUserEmail = env.manualBuildUserEmail
                }

                if(blockPipeline == false) {
                    prodBranch = env.production_branch
                    deployPath = env[buildEnv + 'DeployPath']
                    print '${env.gitlab_api_url}'
                    response = httpRequest ignoreSslErrors:true, acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', url: "${env.gitlab_api_url}/projects/${projectId}?private_token=${gitlab_api_access_tocken}&pretty=true"
                    def project = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(response.content)
                    sourceUrl = project.http_url_to_repo
                    buildEnv = env.Build_Environment
                    sourceBranch = env[buildEnv.toLowerCase() + '_branch']
                    prodBranch = env.production_branch
                    deployPath = env[buildEnv + 'DeployPath']
                }     
                deleteDir()
                sh 'mkdir .tmp'
            }

            if(blockPipeline){
                print ("Pipeline is blocked. " + sourceBranch + " is a unconfigured branch!")
                return
            }

            stage('Checkout & Build') {   
                if(sourceUrl && sourceBranch){
                    dir('.tmp'){
                        sh 'pwd' 
                        sh 'ls -al'
                        credentialsId:credentialsId, url:sourceUrl
                        try {
                            sh ('git checkout ' + sourceBranch)
                        } catch(err) {
                            print 'Branch not available ['+sourceBranch+']'
                            try {
                                sh ('git checkout ' + prodBranch)
                            } catch(proerr) {
                                print 'Production branch not available'
                                sh ('git checkout master')
                            }
                        }

                        sh ('git log --pretty=oneline -3')
                        ommitters = sh(script:"git log -3 --format=%ae, | tr -d '\n'", returnStdout: true).trim()
                        sh 'npm i'
                        nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'Grunt') {   
                            sh 'grunt'                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Deploy') {  
                dir('.tmp'){
                    if(fileExists('dist')){
                         try {
                            build job: 'dev-file-remover', parameters: [
                            string(name: 'deployPath', value: "apps/myapps/dsm/container_1/web/myproject_01/"),
                            string(name: 'uiFolder', value: "hotel-ui-main")
                            ]
                        } catch(err) {
                            print 'Directory doesnt exist to clean'
                            error 'error...'
                        }
                        sh ('scp -r dist ' + deployPath + '/tcp/myproject_01/')
                    }
                }
            }

        }catch(e){
            // send to email
            recipientList = committers.concat(env.tl_email)
            emailext (
                subject: "$env.JOB_NAME - Build #$env.BUILD_NUMBER - FAILED",
                body: '''${SCRIPT,template="build-fail.template"}''',
                to: "${recipientList}"
            )
            throw e
        }finally{
            if (currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().getResult().toString() != "SUCCESS" &&
                (currentBuild.result != 'FAILURE' && currentBuild.result != 'ABORTED')) 
            {
                print 'Sending build success notification emails...'
                // send recovery email
                recipientList = committers.concat(env.tl_email)
                emailext (
                    subject: "$env.JOB_NAME - Build #$env.BUILD_NUMBER - SUCCESS",
                    body: '''${SCRIPT,template="build-success.template"}''',
                    to: "${recipientList}"
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Bower.json

```
    {
      "name": "hotel-contract-module",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "authors": [
        "ds <my-email>"
      ],
      "license": "www.expressSaaS.com",
      "dependencies": {
        "grunt-exsaas-content": "ssh://git@<my_gitlab_ip>:20022/myproject_01/common/ui/ui-static-content-module.git",
        "grunt-exsaas-common": "ssh://git@<my_gitlab_ip>:20022/myproject_01/common/ui/ui-common-lib.git",
        "grunt-exsaas-main": "ssh://git@<my_gitlab_ip>:20022/myproject_01/common/ui/ui-main-lib.git",
        "grunt-exsaas-resource": "ssh://git@<my_gitlab_ip>:20022/myproject_01/common/ui/ui-resource.git"
      }
    }
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: #1 As I can see, **grunt-exsaas-resource** is genetating the delay? #2 are your bower.json dependencies private?

Comment: Thank you for you comment  @JRichardsz, #1 I don't think grunt-exsaas-resource is genetating the delay cuz when I build this in my local environment with grunt build command, it download all the repositories and got build successfully. #2 yes those are private dependencies.

Comment: mmm I can see in your log, that all depedencies, except grunt-exsaas-resource , were downloaded. Am i Ok?

Comment: well.. when I build the project on my local, everything was downloaded and built successful, but when it runs on the Jenkins build, it doesn't clone any repositories not only grunt-exsaas-resource.

Comment: If your repositories will be public, jenkins and another tools, could downloaded them without any problem. Could you try to clone one of this private dependencies using jenkins in another job. Im sure that your problem is th ssh agent and/or private keys

Comment: yeah, Thanks it was a ssh issue. :)